# IllegalArgumentException in createBitmap

Tags: java, android

Im have a problem. On some devices I sometimes (not always) get an IllegalArgumentException error while creating a bitmap. What could be the reason?

**Code:**

```java
public class MStick {

    public MStick(Context context, ViewGroup layout, int stick_res_id) {
        mContext = context;
        stick = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getApplicationContext().getResources(), stick_res_id);
    }

    public void setStick(int stick_res_id) {
        stick = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), stick_res_id);
        setStickSize(stick_width, stick_height);
    }

    public void setStickSize(int width, int height) {
        stick = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(stick, width, height, true);
        stick_width = stick.getWidth();
        stick_height = stick.getHeight();
    }

}

mStick = new MStick(context, layout_mstick, R.drawable.mstick);
mStick.setStickSize(100, 100);
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:1113)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:952)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap.java:807)
  at view.MStick.setStickSize (MStick.java:257)
```

Comment: What is your android sdk version ?

Comment: Target is 30, error occurs on 30 and 31

Comment: Are the width and height always with fixed value 100? or a variable ?

Comment: No. It is like this: setStickSize(layout_mstick.getWidth()/3, layout_mstick.getHeight()/3);

Comment: Could you reproduce it and log the parameters such as width, height,  layout_mstick.getWidth(), layout_mstick.getHeight()  ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not during the error, I have no error at home, but I can see it in the play console ...

Comment: Your best bet is to investigate the method which is called where the exception is thrown and identify in which situations it can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `Exception` means that `stick.getWidth()` or `stick.getHeight()` is `0`.

`drawable/mstick` is probably not a valid resource.

Comment: But why does this only happen sometimes. If resource were not valid, the error would be every time.

Comment: @drmtemtem123 Im not sure, it works on all versions in my app. Try using context.getResources() directly and printing out the height and width after creating an MStick instance. What results do you get?